# Parsing Feed with GSON Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, gson, android-volley

I have a JSON in the following form :-

```
{

    students: [
                    {
                        name:"ABC",
                        deptt:"Physics",
                        year:"1st"  
                    },
                    {
                        name:"XYZ",
                        deptt:"Mathematics",
                        year:"2nd"
                    }
            ]
}
```

I get this response from a webservice which I call using Volley library. I am storing this response in a string.

Now to parse this feed, I am trying to use GSON library. I created a class called Students as below :-

```
public class Students{

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("deptt")
    private String deptt;

    @SerializedName("year")
    private String year;


    public Students(String name,String deptt,String year)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.deptt = deptt;
        this.year = year;
    }

    //followed by getters and setter for each member
}
```

**EDIT**

After my call to the webservice is completed I call another function (as below to parse the feed)

```
public void parseTheFeed(String data) 
{
    Log.d("Data",data);
    Gson gSon = new Gson();
    Students studentData = gSon.fromJson(data,Students.class); //data == feed from webservice
    Log.d("StudentData-Title", studentData.getName());
}
```

Please note I call the method "parseTheFeed(String data)" inside `onResponse` of Volley.

But I am getting **NullPointerException** error while using the Log.d statement. The error message is **"println needs a message"**

Comment: show how you assign `data`. the problem lies there.

Comment: @leeor :- edited the question. Inside onResponse of volley, I call another method called `parseTheFeed(String data)` and pass the return value of `onResponse` (i.e result) to the `parseTheFeed(String data)`

Comment: It seems like the `data` that you pass as a parameter is `null`, show us how do you call `parseTheFeed` method

Comment: @dazito:- I just put a log statement to check for `data` inside `parseTheFeed(String data)`... its not null.

Comment: @JhilmilChatterjee what is the value of `data` then?

Comment: @leeor :- data=`"{"student":[{"name":"ABC","deptt":"Physics","year":"1st"},{"name":"XYZ","deptt":"Mathematics","year":"2nd"}]}"`. Its a json response as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model doesn't match the structure of the data you want to represent.  From your example data your model should more like this.  Then `Gson` will properly handle the data you specified.

```
public class School {
    public List<Student> students;

    public static class Student {
        private String name;
        private String deptt;
        private String year;

        public Student(String name,String deptt,String year)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.deptt = deptt;
            this.year = year;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice your `student` field is actually a `JSONArray` of `Student` `JSONObjects` and the list is contained in a parent `JSONObject`

Using the above you can parse it into a java object from json easily

```
School school = new Gson().fromJson(data, School.class);
List<Student> students = school.students;
// do something with list of students
```

Also note `@SerializedName` is absent.  This annotation is used if you want to change the name of a field.  For instance if we wanted to name the `School#students` field to `School#scholors` we would use it.  Example using your data and my model class

```
public class School {
    @SerializedName("students")
    public List<Student> scholors;
        ...
}
```

Comment: this worked ... so basically, I was wrong while construction the modal class for the feed from webservice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having a wrapper class for `Student`s is not absolutely necessary. In case, your application domain model didn't have a school entity to begin with and you wouldn't want to add it just for the sake of JSON desrialization, you can directly unmarshall your students into a `List`.

```
// input is your web service response
JsonObject data = gson.fromJson(input, JsonObject.class);

// collect Students into a List
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>() {}.getType();
List<Student> students = gson.fromJson(data.getAsJsonArray("students"), type);

// access a Student object
System.out.println(students.get(0).getName()); // ABC
```

Here `Student` is the same old POJO class *(but named as singular)*

```
public class Student {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("deptt")
    private String deptt;

    @SerializedName("year")
    private String year;


    public Student(String name, String deptt, String year)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.deptt = deptt;
        this.year = year;
    }

    // followed by getters and setter for each member
}
```